# Check if more than one checkbox is selected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, checkbox, checked

I need to know if more than one checkbox is selected from my list.

How to achive this using jQuery?

I've tried something with `:checked`, but no success.

Thanks all for help!

Comment: Does `selected` mean `checked`? Can you post the relevant parts of your markup, and the code you have so far?

Comment: Please post your html and javascript source code. For help we have to take look on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your container will have an id

```
if ($("#containerID input:checkbox:checked").length > 1) {
   // your code goes here
}
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4HJv/)

Answer (score 4):

```
var n = $("input:checked").length;
if (n >= 2)
   ...
```

Comment: I'd say the other answer is better because this one initializes a cosmetic variable. It would be marginally better to cache the `$('input:checked')` instead, if you really had to cache some value. Otherwise, don't cache values meant for a single use / conditional.

Comment: But it's not the $('input:checked') that is cached. It's $('input:checked').length! Of course there is no difference in this regard between two answers.

Comment: Exactly. It would have been better to cache `$('input:checked')` than to cache `$('input:checked').length`, **if you really had to cache anything at all**. By saying `var n = $('input:checked').length`, you're putting the same semantic value / meaning into two different positions in memory, which is a waste.

Comment: But I think there is a difference between caching an Integer and the huge structures of jQuery selectors. I don't think that caching an Integer has such importance.

Comment: @richardneililagan - hardly worth worrying about such minor memory use considering the resources consumed in the call to `$('input:checked')`.

Comment: @RobG - that's why I'm pointing out that if there's something to be cached, it's the selector. You wouldn't want to be doing the select again, considering the resources consumed as you said. Point being, there's nothing that should be cached. If there is (maybe because it's needed somewhere in the code), then the thing to cache is the select, not the scalar. I admit it's minor, shyeah, but hey, small steps towards better coding.